# BASH: Cannot awk with a variable in a while loop

Tags: bash, awk

I have a Problem when trying to awk a READ input in a while loop.

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter the Array LUN ID (ALU) you wish to query, separated by a comma (e.g. 2036,2037,2045): " ARRAY_LUNS
LUN_NUMBER=`echo $ARRAY_LUNS | awk -F "," '{ for (i=1; i<NF; i++) printf $i"\n" ; print $NF }' | wc -w`
echo "you entered $LUN_NUMBER LUN's"

s=0
while [ $s -lt $LUN_NUMBER ];
do
        s=$[$s+1]
        LUN_ID=`echo $ARRAY_LUNS | awk -F, '{print $'$s'}' | awk -v n1="$s" 'NR==n1'`
        echo "NR $s :"
        echo "awk -v n1="$s" 'NR==n1'$LUN_ID"
done
```

No matter what options with awk i try, i dont get it to display more than the first entry before the comma. It looks to me, like the loop has some problems to get the variable s counted upwards. But on the other hand, the code line:

```
LUN_ID=`echo $ARRAY_LUNS | awk -F, '{print $'$s'}' | awk -v n1="$s" 'NR==n1'`
```

works just great! Any idea on how to solve this. Another solution to my READ input would be just fine as well.

Comment: What data are you entering for `ARRAY_LUNS` variable?

Comment: The first three lines might be easily changed by using an array: `IFS=, read -a -p "Please···" ARRAY_LUNS; LUN_NUMBER="${#ARRAY_LUNS[@]}"`. In fact, the commas used as separator might be removed and instead use white spaces.

Comment: @Jdamian: `s=$[$s+1]` is the less common way of writing `(( s++ ))`.

Comment: An the `loop` might be `for((s=0;i<LUN_NUMBER;s++)); do echo "$s: ${ARRAY_LUNS[s]}"; done`

Comment: Your `awk` code to compute the number of values entered (LUN_NUMBER variable) can be made simpler: LUN_NUMBER=$(echo "$ARRAY_LUNS" | awk -F, 'print NF') -- No `awk` loop is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

typeset -a ARRAY_LUNS
IFS=, read -a -p "Please enter the Array LUN ID (ALU) you wish to query, separated by a comma (e.g. 2036,2037,2045): " ARRAY_LUNS
LUN_NUMBER="${#ARRAY_LUNS[@]}"
echo "you entered $LUN_NUMBER LUNs"

for((s=0;s<LUN_NUMBER;s++))
do
     echo "LUN id $s: ${ARRAY_LUNS[s]}"
done
```

### Why does your `awk` code not work?

The problem is not the counter. I said `The last awk command in the pipe` i.e.

`awk -v n1="$s" 'NR==n1'`.

This `awk` code tries to print the first line when `s` is 1, the second line when `s` is 2, the third line when `s` is 3, and so on... But ***how many lines are printed by `echo $ARRAY_LUNS`***? Just ***ONE***... there is no second line, no third line... just ***ONE line*** and just ***ONE line*** is printed.

That line contains all `LUN_IDs` in ***ONE LINE***, i.e, one LUN_ID next to another LUN_ID, like this way:

```
34 45 21 223
```

***NOT***  this way

```
34
45
21
223
```

Those `LUN_IDs` are ***fields*** printable by `awk` using `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, ... and so on.
Therefore if you want you code to run fine just ***remove that last command in the pipe***:

```
LUN_ID=$(echo "$ARRAY_LUNS" | awk -F, '{print $'$s'}')
```

Please, for any further question, firstly read this [awk guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)

Comment: Hi Jdamian, I only enter numeric values after the read input.
I have realized it with an array like you stated above, thats a different approach than i tried it with a variable but its working.

Is it possible, to get the input done with separated commas, and then afterwards awk'ing them each out of the input? I thought my approach would be doing just fine, but it doesn't. It keeps awking the first input before the comma just fine and then every input after this is just blank.

Comment: Your awk code does not work because the line you think is working is just the unique one that is not working. The last awk command in the pipe ***ONLY prints ONE line*** in each iteration: the `s-th` line... but think carefully, how many lines does print your `echo $ARRAY_LUNS`? Just ONE.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply!
I still dont quite get it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply!
I still dont quite get it.
The code line:
`echo "NR $s :"`
is working great. It shows me for every number entered and separated by a comma, the right counter. E.G: i enter five LUN Numbers separated by comma. The code Displays: NR 1: Nr 2: Nr 3: Nr 4: Nr 5:

So i think, `$s` is counting properly for each entry. But in this code snippet:
`awk -F, '{print $'$s'}'`
it seems like $s is only counting the first number and no more. I think I miss something here in my understanding.
I thought the "translated" awk line has to look like:
`awk -F, '{print $1}'` $2 etc pp...

Comment: Thanks, now i get the idea!